# How can I make hot corners less sensitive?

Tags: unity, unity-tweak-tool

On Unity desktop, I have enabled hot corners using. Unity Tweak Tool. It's just that they are too sensitive, I too often activate them by mistake.

I couldn't find an option to set a delay for it in the tool, is there any way to do that?

Just an image of how I am left without that option

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can edit the delay of hotcorners by installing the compizconfig-settings-manager (Ubuntu Software Centre). In the settings manager you can edit the 'edge trigger delay' in general optoins, for example, try 250.

Comment: The option can be found under "General Options", under the "General" tab. The default value is 0.

Comment: Is this setting is milliseconds?

Comment: respect sensei, as you walk the path before me and solve it and share it with us, much respect.